# Angular js - Not able to push to an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to push some info to an array and show it with ng-repeat but for some reason it's not working

This is my controller:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.article')
    .controller('Article', Article);

function Article($location) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.comments = [];
    vm.addComment = addComment;

    function addComment() {
        vm.comments.push(vm.newComment);
        vm.newComment = {};
    }


}

})();
```

Here's the plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/jPOJDXoG1vgNfsDzyJAD?p=preview

Thanks for the help

Comment: you really should include *all* the relevant code in the question body.  In particular, the HTML.  In the current plunker you linked, the JavaScript is using the `controller as` syntax, and you declared your `ng-controller` this way, `ng-controller="Article as vm"`, but the data bound items are using `$scope` syntax (i.e., they are not referring to `vm` at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for your controller you are using a controller As syntax so you will have to refer to scope variables with a prefix of `vm`.

```
<div ng-controller="Article as vm">
    <form ng-submit="vm.addComment()">
        <textarea placeholder="Sign in to share your thoughts." ng-model="vm.newComment.comment"></textarea>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.newComment.user">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Post">
    </form>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="comment in vm.comments">{{comment.user}} - {{comment.comment}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also in your controller you have to initialize a newComment object

```
function Article($location) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.comments = [];
    vm.addComment = addComment;
    vm.newComment = {user: '', comment: ''}
    function addComment() {
        vm.comments.push(vm.newComment);
        vm.newComment = {};
    }


}
```

[Updated Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3SQPqIzpTafCbMKJibqm?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @eltonKamami, you're right, I missed the controller as syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="Article as vm">
        <form ng-submit="vm.addComment()">
            <textarea placeholder="Sign in to share your thoughts." ng-model="vm.newComment.comment"></textarea>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.newComment.user">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Post">
        </form>

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="comment in vm.comments">{{comment.user}} - {{comment.comment}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is the updated plunkr
https://plnkr.co/edit/HK4WIYCF6poMXncBU9Uk?p=preview